# A stochastic matrix $B = \lambda(\lambda I - A)^{-1}$ such that $B-B^2$ has a non-negative diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I apologize if this is too elementary a question, but I have not been able to make much progress.

Consider a real matrix $A$ with $A_{ij} >0$ for $i \ne j$ and $\sum_{j} A_{ij} = 0$ for each $j$. The matrix $A$ is the generator matrix for some continuous-time Markov chain $M$. Define the matrix
$$
B = \lambda (\lambda I - A)^{-1}
$$
for some $\lambda > 0$.
The matrix $B$ is a stochastic matrix that describes the behavior of $M$ over time intervals of random length $t \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$.

**Conjecture.** The diagonal entries of the matrix $B - B^2$ are non-negative.

The conjecture is not true for an arbitrary stochastic matrix $B$, but in numerical simulations it seems to be true for stochastic matrices of the special form above. I was not able to make much progress toward proving the conjecture, so any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Do you know an interpretation of $B^2$ in the context of continuous-time MC?

Comment: $B^2$ gives transitions over a time interval of length $t = t_1+t_2$, where $t_i \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$. So the conjecture can be rephrased as $$\mathbb{P}(\mbox{in state $i$ at time $t$} \mid \mbox{in state $i$ at time $0$, $t \sim Exp(\lambda)$}) \ge \mathbb{P}(\mbox{in state $i$ at time $t$} \mid \mbox{in state $i$ at time $0$, $t=t_1+t_2$, $t_1,t_2 \sim Exp(\lambda)$}).$$ Not sure how helpful this is though, it seems like an intuitive statement but it is not true in general that the probability to be in state $i$ at time $t$ (conditional on being in state $i$ at time $0$) decreases